# How to create empty table in Ballerina and to add the records gradually

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I need to create an empty and add records gradually to the created table. How can I do that with Ballerina? What are the possible functions which are applicable to a table in Ballerina?

Here is my record

```
type Employee record {|
    readonly string name;
    string department;
|};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty table using an empty table constructor with no members. You can use the `add` or `put` functions from the table langlib to add members.

```
type Employee record {|
    readonly string name;
    string department;
|};

public function main() {
    table<Employee> key(name) tb = table [];

    tb.add({name: "Emma", department: "IT"});
}
```

[`add`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.table/0.0.0/functions#add) panics if there is already a member with the specified key whereas [`put`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.table/0.0.0/functions#put) replaces the member.

See [API docs for the table langlib](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.table/0.0.0) for all functions.